# How can I implement values for Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, roles

I am making this MERN RBAC full-stack application and I've been having a problem assigning roles to a value. I need an admin and super admin. when I implement the values into the frontend nothing happens. I believe I need something in the userRouter.js but I don't know what. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? It is greatly appreciated.

userRouter.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");


// router.get("/role", (req, res) => {
//   const role = req.bodyrole;

//   db.query(
//     role,
//     (err, result) => {
//       if(err) {
//         res.send({err:err})
//       }
//     }
//   )


// })

// Read Users 
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.find().exec((err, users) =>{
      if(err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, users: users }); 
  });
});

// Delete Users
router.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).exec((err, deleteItem) => {
      if(err){
          res.send(err);
      } 
      return res.json(deleteItem);
  })
})

// register
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password, passwordVerify, role } = req.body;

    // validation

    if (!name || !email || !password || !passwordVerify || !role)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter all required fields." });

    if (password.length < 6)
      return res.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "Please enter a password of at least 6 characters.",
      });

    if (password !== passwordVerify)
      return res.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "Please enter the same password twice.",
      });

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser)
      return res.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "An account with this email already exists.",
      });

    // hash the password

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    // save a new user account to the db

    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      passwordHash,
      role
    });

    const savedUser = await newUser.save();

    // sign the token

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        user: savedUser._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    // send the token in a HTTP-only cookie

    res
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
      })
      .send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

// log in

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // validate

    if (!email || !password)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter all required fields." });

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!existingUser)
      return res.status(401).json({ errorMessage: "Wrong email or password." });

    const passwordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingUser.passwordHash
    );
    if (!passwordCorrect)
      return res.status(401).json({ errorMessage: "Wrong email or password." });

    // sign the token

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        user: existingUser._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    // send the token in a HTTP-only cookie

    res
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
      })
      .send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  res
    .cookie("token", "", {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(0),
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    })
    .send();
});

router.get("/loggedIn", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (!token) return res.json(false);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    res.send(true);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(false);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  passwordHash: { type: String, required: true },
  role: {type: String, enum: ["admin", "superadmin"]}
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

auth.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthContextProvider(props) {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);

  async function getLoggedIn() {
    const loggedInRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth/loggedIn");
    // const loggedInRes = await axios.get(
    //   "https://mern-auth-template-tutorial.herokuapp.com/auth/loggedIn"
    // );
    setLoggedIn(loggedInRes.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AuthContext;
export { AuthContextProvider };
```

frontend user1.js (This doesn't work)

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';

import User from "./User";

export default function User1() {
    const [role, setRole] =useState("");

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth").then((response) => {
            if (response.data.loggedIn == true) {
                setRole(response.data.user[0].role);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {role == "superadmin" && <User/>}
            {/* <User/> */}
            {role == "admin" && <User/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

user.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    Box,
    Heading,
    TextInput,
    Table,
    TableHeader,
    TableRow,
    TableCell,
    Text,
    TableBody,
    Button,
} from "grommet";
import {
    Search,
    Edit,
    Trash
} from "grommet-icons";

    class User extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
        users: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsers()
    }

    
    getUsers(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth").then((res) => {
        if(res.data.success){
            this.setState({
            users: res.data.users,
            });
            console.log("users: ", this.state.users);
        }
        });
    }

    onDelete = (id) => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/auth/delete/${id}`).then((res) => {
        alert(res.data.name + " has been deleted successfully");
        this.getUsers();
        })
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <Box className="container">
            <Box >
            <Box alignSelf="center">
                <Heading>All Users</Heading>
            </Box>
            <Box direction="row" align="center"alignSelf="center" gap="small">
                <Search />
                <TextInput
                className="form-control"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                name="searchTerm"
                onChange={this.handleTextSearch}
                ></TextInput>
            </Box>
            </Box>
            

            <Table alignSelf="center">
            <TableHeader >
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">#</Text></TableCell >
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">Name</Text></TableCell >
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">Email</Text></TableCell >
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">Password</Text></TableCell >
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">Role</Text></TableCell >
                    <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">Actions</Text></TableCell >
                    
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody >
            
            {this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
                <TableRow>
                
                    <TableCell ><Text size="large" >{index}</Text></TableCell>
                
                <TableCell align="center" alignSelf="center" alignContent="center">
                    <Text size="large">{user.name}</Text>
                </TableCell >
                <TableCell><Text size="large">{user.email}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell><Text size="large">{user.passwordHash}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell><Text size="large">{user.role}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell gap="xsmall" direction="row">
                        <Button href="#" onClick={() => this.onDelete(user._id)} color="red">
                            <Box direction="row" align="center" alignSelf="center" gap="xxsmall">
                                <Trash color="red" />
                                <Text size="large">Delete</Text>
                            </Box>
                        </Button>
                </TableCell >
                </TableRow >
            ))}
            </TableBody>
            </Table>
            <Box width="small" alignSelf="center" >
            <Button type="button" color="#99CCFF"  href="/register" label="Add New User" ></Button>
            </Box>
        </Box>







        )
    }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: may you console log the response.data.user[0] and see what is returns?

Comment: The route `http://localhost:5000/auth` returns `{ success: true, users: users }` but your condition checks `response.data.loggedIn` property in `User1` function. Just add console.logs to see what data you're getting. Make sure the request goes to the right url and returns the right data.